# Authentication of HTTP request from an Android App to A Google Cloud Engine App

Tags: java, android, rest, google-app-engine, authentication

I am planning to develop an Android app that will make HTTP request to a REST API (server app) that is hosted on Google App Engine. The data retrieve would be common and visible to all users of the app, so authentication at a user level doesn't not seem necessary. My concern is this, is it necessary for the server app to authenticate that the request is indeed from the intended Android app? If so, is this done internally by the libraries or do I need to implement it myself? Some reading materials on this topic would be very much helpful.

Going through the Google documentations have indicated that the use of a Service Account would seem appropriate, but it bothers me that I would then need to package the credentials along with the Android app, which some how seems to defeat the purpose of authenticating the request, since it's is relatively easy to retrieve the credentials from an apk.

Any guidance in terms of design would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that API Keys is the answer. API Keys can be selected to be limited to a certain Android App during creation.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/restricting-api-access-with-api-keys-frameworks